# Github and Spyder

Tags: github, spyder

I've be writing code with a friend in Pycharm, this has been linked to Github. I wanted to start doing the same with Spyder. This isn't obvious and I was wondering if anyone had found a way to connect to Github with Spyder so we can easily push and pull code. During my research a spyder developer mentioned this wasn't possible (date 2017), does anyone know if there is an update to this? Seems like it should be possible! Thanks

Comment: The docs mention very limited git support through gitk and a git terminal.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It's still not possible to connect Spyder directly to Github, sorry.